# How to get all type of file extensions within a directory using os.walk or glob.glob

Tags: python, file-extension, os.walk, language-detection

I have a code that detects language of files from a directory. But while mentioning about the type of extension how can I detect language of all file extensions (example:-  .pdf, .xlsx, .docx etc etc) in the directory and not only .txt files which is mentioned in the code. Attaching code for reference. I would like to know how this can be done using glob and os.walk.

```
import csv
from fnmatch import fnmatch
try:
    from langdetect import detect
except ImportError:
    detect = lambda _: '<dunno>'
import os

rootdir = '.'  # current directory
extension = '.txt'
file_pattern = '*' + extension

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile)

    for dirpath, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(os.path.abspath(rootdir)):
        for filename in filenames:
            if fnmatch(filename, file_pattern):
                lang = detect(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
                csvwriter.writerow([dirpath, filename, lang])
```

Comment: If you really mean what you wrote: "all" file extensions: simply replace `txt` by `*`. But I _ guess_ you mean "more than one single file extension, i.e. this list instead of `.txt` only: [ '.pdf', '.xlsx', '.docx']". right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you could replace your `fnmatch` check by

```
eoi = ['*.pdf', '*.xlsx', '*.docx', '*.txt']     # extensions of interest list
if any(fnmatch(file, ext) for ext in eoi):
    lang = ...
```

Comment: Works. Thank you. How can I avoid writing this part then ""extension = '.txt'"" so that it takes .txt along with other file extensions
'

Comment: Just add any file extension to the list in the LC in the conditional. Please see my edit if it addresses your question.

Comment: Thanks. On another note I don't think the code is reading the content of each file and taking a decision on the language. How shall I add it in the code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure iiuc... - do you mean the filtering for the desired file extensions works now, but besides that you have another question about the language detection part?

Comment: Ok, then you should perhaps place a new question about that. I don't have any experience with `langdetect`.